# jqGrid (Free version) and SQL Server 2012 and FileTables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, hyperlink, jqgrid

Using the most recent version of jqGrid (free version) in ASP.NET single web page and currently have a grid that references an XML (static) dataset. Within the dataset, there is a file name that I have formatted as a hyperlink. The grid functions, and the hyperlink works. When the hyperlink is clicked, it opens a PDF file in a new tab in the web browser.

Some of the code is below:

```
       $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
            url: "Myfile.xml",
            xmlReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: "Recordset",
                row: "Record",
                id: "[setEntry]"
            },
            datatype: "xml",
```

.. and so on.

The user would like me to put this in a SQL Server 2012 database, and if possible, utilize the FileTables functionality, to store not only the data displayed in the grid, but the PDF file also, and to have that same hyperlink function the same way.

Questions:

- When the grid is loaded, it selects the entire XML dataset, and I use the functionality of the grid's search and filter tools.  How do you make it read a SQL Server 2012 table instead? We do not use PHP.
- Second, assuming that I can read the SQL table (a `select *` statement), can I do essentially the same thing as before - hyperlink to the PDF file which instead of being stored in a virtual folder on the IIS server resides instead in the FileTables in SQL Server?

Comment: The question seems to me for about 99% for the server implementation. You need just provide the URL for jqGrid which returns the same data for filling the grid. The URLs placed in the grid should point to static PDF files (on the web server) or to ASP.NET which returns PDF as binary data and adds `"Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=someFile.pdf"` in HTTP header. The client will be able to save or directly display the data like static PDF files.

Comment: How do you make jqGrid execute a stored procedure to do the intial select from the dataset, if you don't use PHP?  Right now, the XML file is included with the web app, and the XML reader does the work.

Comment: jqGrid if pure JavaScript solution. It will make HTTP request to your ASP.NET code. The code will for example `var con = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.DB);` to open Database, to use `var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spYouStoredProcedure", con) {  CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }}; con.Open(); var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();` to execute store procedure and then `while (dr.Read()) {...}` to read the results. You can return the results as JSON. So all implementation is in the server code.